# Notify a thread when I/O is possible on a socket

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am building an online multi-player game server. Currently the networking architecture is quite simple: the acceptor thread is an infinite loop that just sits waiting on accept(). If it gets a connection then it sets everything up and spawns a thread to handle communication with that client.

My problem arises after I get the login packet, because the thread should just wait until there's any data to read (a new packet like "attack this creature", arrives). I know the flag O_ASYNC will make system fire a SIGIO, but since threads have the same PID on linux the signal is caught by the whole process.

Is there an efficient way to get the thread notified when there's data to read so it knows when to parse the packet and eventually call worker thread to handle the command?

Edit: forgot to mention that I set socket to O_NONBLOCK so read() does not block, because the client thread may get called at any time by another thread.

Comment: If you spawn a new thread for the client, that thread can just wait/block until there's data available by calling read()/recv() or similar.on the socket.

Comment: Why? When I/O is possible, and specifically when there is data to be read, it will complete without blocking. What do you need a thread for?

Comment: @user207421 I updated the question. The client thread can't block on read since it may get called at any time by worker/main thread

Comment: Read what I wrote, and try to make sense yourself. If you're using non-blocking mode, the client thread cannot block *at all*, by definition, and you don't *need* a client thread if you are using non-blocking mode *at all,* and *particularly* if you are driving your I/O off 'there's data to be read'. You also need to clarify what you think 'calling' a thread from another thread actually means.

Comment: A thread cannot be called from another thread, only signalled.  Call/return does not change thread context.  Your concerns are unclear:(

Comment: What does each thread do when it's not doing IO?  If it would simply be waiting for a signal that it needs to do IO, drop the non-blocking sockets and just have each thread wait for input via `read()` or `recv()`.  Because there's no point in blocking while waiting for a signal from another thread to perform IO when the thread that needs to do IO can just access a normal, blocking descriptor.

Comment: @Andrew the client thread is awaiting for the main thread to fire a signal to it

Comment: *the client thread is awaiting for the main thread to fire a signal to it*  A signal that means what?  "You have IO waiting on your socket"?  Again - that's pointless.  Just use a blocking socket and have the thread block in `recv()` or `read()` and get its data directly.  You're adding needless complexity.  If you're creating a thread per client socket, there's no need to have the main thread poll all the sockets - there is already client thread that can do its own work.  That architecture doesn't scale as well, but I seriously doubt you need to address that problem

Comment: One thread per connection is always a bad design (google for context switch). You should think about using a threadpool to communicate with clients or just use a single thread apporach when it's fast enough.

Comment: @user743414 In fact, I dont create the threads when the client connects. I allocate the memory at the start of the game-server on an ``int8_t[0x44C0000]`` and when a new client thread is started I just assign it a part of this memory (0x44C) with ``pthread_attr_setstack``. This way I can manage up to 1100 simultaneous connections and avoid the ``pthread_create`` overhead

Answer (score 1):

Use `select()` or `epoll()` (on Linux) or `kqueue` (on BSD).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Linux.
I recommend you to just drop thread and start using epoll. Epoll can take multiple file descriptor and watch over all of them.

You can start here : https://kovyrin.net/2006/04/13/epoll-asynchronous-network-programming/
Or here : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html

Comment: Would it make sense to use epoll on my worker thread and have it fire a SIGIO to the client thread with pthread_kill when I/O is possible?

Comment: Not really you should use epoll on your main thread and maybe start a new thread when there is data to read on a socket. But I don't recommand using thread in your situation.